# Memory allocation / release in C

Tags: c, arrays, malloc, declaration

I know that in language like c I need to free the memory after I allocate it. ( I am coming from java), regarding this I have a couple of questions:

1. when I am doing:

   ```
   int array[30];
   ```

   (i.e creating an array of size 30 integers) is this the same as
   doing?

   ```
   int array[] = malloc(sizeof(int)*30);
   ```
2. As a sequence to the first question,   when I create array(s) 
   inside a function (i.e local to the function and not global to the
   whole file),   do I need to free the memory for this array inside
   the function where I create it?     (I don't see any other way to
   free it since I can't pass a reference of all arrays created back to
   the main() function).

So in short, i want to know exactly when do I need to free memory for objects/primitives created (in or outside of a function).

Comment: Please have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/79923/what-and-where-are-the-stack-and-heap).This is not answer but it will surely throw some light.

Comment: @user2030118 please use I instead of i for self reference.

Comment: Thanks for the link, i will have a look

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you say

```
int array[30];
```

this is on the stack and will automatically get cleaned up for you when it goes out of scope.

If you say

```
int * array = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int)*30);
```

the memory will be allocated on the free store (heap), and you are in charge of freeing it

```
free(array);
```

The same applies whether the code is, be that inside a function call, or in main.
If you use `malloc`, you need to use `free`.

Answer (score 5):

No, it's not the same at all.

The first one reserves memory using "automatic allocation", which is generally on the stack. This memory will be automatically de-allocated once the object goes out of scope, as in when the function returns for instance.

The second one uses `malloc()` to allocate memory "on the heap"; this memory must be de-allocated using `free()` when no longer needed.

Also, the proper syntax is:

```
int *array = malloc(30 * sizeof *int);
```

You can't use `[]` like that in C.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `int array[30]`, you allocate the array on the stack and it lives only in the scope it was created in. 
If you use `malloc`, the memory must be released manually with `free`.

Both approaches are different, and serve different needs. Stack-allocated variables/objects have a limited scope whereas you can use `malloc`'d objects beyond the local scope.

Use `malloc` with pointers, though:

```
int *array = malloc(sizeof(int)*30);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your array `int array[30]` will be put on the stack and its allocates memory will automatically be released, once `array` goes out of scope. But, when you allocate memory using `malloc/calloc/realloc` you need to explicitly `free` this memory.

Answer (score 0):

Basically `malloc` allocates memory in the heap and does not get freed after losing scope. So memory allocated using `malloc` should be freed using `free`.